# Mysql check if row has child records in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Hello here is my table structure

[image]

I am trying to determine does record with ID 1 has child records (parent_id column ), and this should work for all record not just for specific one

Trying something like this

```
SELECT id, ??? as 'has_child_rows' FROM image_tree WHERE parent_id IS NULL
```

Any idea left join, recursion, subquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exists` and an inline correlated subquery:

```
select 
    id,
    exists(select 1 from image_tree t1 where t1.parent_id = t.id) has_child_rows
from image_tree t
```

This returns all the rows in the table, with a boolean value that indicates whether a child record exists.

To filter on the record that has `id = 1`, just add a `where` clause:

```
select 
    id,
    exists(select 1 from image_tree t1 where t1.parent_id = t.id) has_child_rows
from image_tree t
where id = 1
```

Comment: sorry but i can't use value 1 in subquery  since checking multiple rows

Comment: @Ambulancelada: this does what you want. As an explanation: the subquery is wrapped in an `exists` condition. If the subquery produces one or more row, `exists` return 1, else it returns `0`. You can try and run the query against your database, and see what it returns.

Comment: amazing work still dont understand but it's working like charm

Comment: sir is it possible to add extra left join with this query?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is using 'left join' as you mentioned:

```
SELECT
    i.*, IF(p.parent_id IS NULL, 0, 1) AS has_child_rows
FROM image_tree i
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT parent_id FROM image_tree WHERE parent_id IS NOT NULL GROUP BY parent_id) p ON i.id = p.parent_id
WHERE i.parent_id IS NULL
```

In practice, you need to test the performance as I have little knowledge of the table indices, quantities of records and the relations.

Comment: From my experience, if the field 'has_child_rows' is critical and use a lot, then a redundant column should be added and calculated with trigger or command.